# Key code for "mouse key up" and "mouse key down"

Tags: javascript, asp.net

How to access the key code for "mouse key up" in JavaScript?
If I press the left mouse button then key code is one.

I want to fire some code when `onmousekeyup`. But whenever the mouse gets key up, this code does not fire. So I want to try using keycode for mouse key up when key is released (key up).

Answer (score 5):

You don't use "key codes" for mouse events. Try binding things to the `onmouseup` and `onmousedown` events:

```
<a onmousedown="MouseDown(this);" onmouseup="MouseUp(this);">Some Text</a>
```

and with ASP.NET you can add these using the controls attribute collection:

```
TextBox textBox = new TextBox();

textBox.Attributes.Add("onmousedown", "MouseDown(this);");
textBox.Attributes.Add("onmouseup", "MouseUp(this);");
```

which will call the following javascript functions:

```
function MouseDown(theElement) {
    /* do work */
}

function MouseUp(theElement) {
    /* do work */
}
```